# List the elements of the set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on my math homework and I don't even know how to do this or what it is asking. Any help would be great!

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\} \times \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. List the elements of the set $B = \{(s, t) \in A \mid s \geq t \}$.

Comment: Can you write down (or sketch) the set $A$? Do you understand the notation that is used to define $B$?

Answer (score 2):

Here, $A$ is a Cartesian product between two sets, namely $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ and $\left\{1,2,3,4\right\}$. This simply means that $A$ is the set of all possible ordered pairs formed by taking an element in each set.
$$A=\left\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)\right\}$$

Next, the set $B$ is created by taking only those pairs $(s,t)$ of $A$ that satisfy the condition $s\ge t$.

Try to figure the answer by yourself, as this is, after all, homework... Then again, this is SE, so if you want to check, look below.

> $$B=\left\{(1,1),(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\right\}$$